# Debug configuration select options in vscode appearing twice

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

- I don't live in an English-speaking country. I'm sorry for my poor English skills.

[1st = 4th, 2nd = 5th, 3rd = 6th in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQDDS.png)

Debug configuration select options in vscode appearing twice!
How can I fix this error?
I changed mingw once and restarted vscode and my laptop several times but nothing's changed.

My launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations":[
    {
      "name": "C/C++: gcc.exe 활성 파일 빌드 및 디버그",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "gdb에 자동 서식 지정 사용",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
          "description": "디스어셈블리 버전을 Intel(으)로 설정",
          "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe 활성 파일 빌드"
    },
    {
      "name": "C/C++: g++.exe 활성 파일 빌드 및 디버그",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "gdb에 자동 서식 지정 사용",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
          "description": "디스어셈블리 버전을 Intel(으)로 설정",
          "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe 활성 파일 빌드"
    },
    {
      "name": "C/C++: 빌드된 파일 디버그",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "gdb에 자동 서식 지정 사용",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
          "description": "디스어셈블리 버전을 Intel(으)로 설정",
          "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe 활성 파일 빌드",
            "command": "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe 활성 파일 빌드",
            "command": "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: These files are usually auto-generated in a `.vscode` folder, have you checked if there is more than one?

Comment: I couldn't find more files, but I deleted and rewritten the file by referring to your opinion and it was resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related GitHub issues that got closed: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121148 (resolved) and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156632 (needs more detail)

Comment: @lant good to hear it ! I'm happy that somehow I managed to help you to solve your problem!